# Create user credentials in Locust subclass and pass to TaskSet

Tags: locust

I want to provision a user's credentials when locust runs, then pass those credentials to the tasks.

The idea is to provision a user as each user (client) is spawned by locust, and then deprovision the users when locust is stopped.

The user could be provisioned/deprovisioned in a backend system, read from a file or database table, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this.

1. In the TaskSet subclass, implement on_start and on_stop. Set instance variables (self.whatever) to the values provisioned for the "user" (for example, username and password).
2. Use the decorator method of defining tasks. This makes the methods part of the TaskSet subclass, so you can refer to the instance variables with the provisioned values.

For example,

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.username = <however you want to get it>

    @task(1)
    def MyTask(self):
        <wherever you need it> = self.username
```